# Removing duplicate titles retrieved from custom fields. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Following is the code that retrieves and outputs state name from custom select field into a navigation menu. For eg: if there is 5 post under state New York, this code shows only one post of New York in navigation drop down menu as redundant values are removed.. but what i want to do is , when the user clicks new york, it redirects to a new page where all the posts under New York will be displayed.. Same with all the states as well because this is a dynamic menu

```
                    $args = array('post_type' => 'article-form', 'showposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DSC');
                    $city = new WP_Query($args);

                    $states = [];

                    while ( $city->have_posts() ) :
                        $city->the_post();
                        $state = get_field('state');
                        if ( !in_array($state, $states) ) :
                            $states[] = $state;
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #9c9c9c;">
                                    <?php echo $state;
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                                <hr style="margin: 0">
                            </li>
                            <?php

                        endif;
                    endwhile; ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>
```

Comment: If you're building a menu it makes no sense to iterate and link posts when what you really want is a link to an Archive Page. I'd suggest you to read about [Wordpress Menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) and [Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and start again your menu from scratch.

Comment: well this is a dynamic menu.. whenever admin creates a post about any places in the custom post type "Article form" and the state he selects is displayed in the state drop down menu. its the requirement of this project. With your help redundant values are removed. but If New York has 5 posts , above code only displays the latest post. If i am going on a wrong direction, Please give me some guide so that i can finish this. I am really stuck in this.

Comment: Any Help would be appreciated. @Jordi Nebot

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing unique values into an array

```
<?php $stateArray = array(); ?>
<?php while ($city->have_posts()):$city->the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #9c9c9c; "> 
    <?php
        $state = the_field('state');
        if (!in_array($state, $stateArray)):
            echo $state;
            array_push($stateArray, $state);
        endif;
    ?>
    </a>
<hr style="margin:0">
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I hope it helps!

P.S Try to avoid inline css, use and external css file for any kind of stylining. Keep you html files as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

@user3127632's idea of pushing values to an Array to check if they've been printed before is a good one, but there are a couple of mistakes in his/her code.

If you need to store an ACF's field value to a variable, you should use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()` as the last one doesn't return the value but print it. Also, you need to move the `li` and `a` nodes inside the condition, otherwise you won't be echoing the label in your link, but the duplicated link will still be there...

So, it would be something like this:

```
<?php 
$states = [];
while ( $city->have_posts() ) :
    $city->the_post();
    $state = get_field('state');
    if ( !in_array($state, $states) ) :
        $states[] = $state; // A more efficient way to push values to an array
?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #9c9c9c;">
        <?php echo $state; ?>
    </a>
    <hr style="margin: 0">
</li>
<?php
    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome @SujanShrestha! If any of the posted answers solved your question, it's kind of you to accept it! :)

Comment: I have one final issue in my project. Your Above code removes the redundancy of post title.. For eg: if there are 5 post under state New York then only the last value of array will be echoed. How to make an archive page of that state New York, so that whenever user clicks the New York, it redirects to the New York Page archive?
Thanks again for answering.

Comment: I know this using basic php by passing id through url but i want to display the results using wordpress way. @Jordi Nebot

Comment: I guess what you really need here to accomplish that in WP is a [Custom Taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). It allows you to group posts under some kind of specific classification, it provides you an specific URL for referencing this group and of course it has its own archive page where you are allowed to lists posts using WP Loop. I'd suggest you to try the [Custom Posts Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) Plugin. It's a perfect way to create and edit CPT's and Custom Taxonomies too.

Comment: I tried using your plugin but i m not getting my output. what i m basically trying to do is show the list of states in my navigation menu. the code looks like this:

Comment: I can't see any code @SujanShrestha... Anyway, I think it'd be better for you to edit your question and update it with your current achievements and new needs...

Comment: I have updated my question. @ Jordi Nebot . So kind of you to comment and trying to help me. Really appreciate your work sir.